# How to find out highest possible Image resolution to support multple screens

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-drawable, android-image

I'm a little bit confused by Androids approach to support multiple screens. I read the official documentation supporting multiple screens a couple times however I don't fully understand the concept.

In my quiz application every question should have an Image. In total there will be 255 Images. The app supports only landscape and smartphones of all screen sizes (without tablets).

[image]

Now my Designer want to know the highest possible Image resolution to buy the Images this week. I want to implement all Images in the highest resolution because Android will auto-scales the drawables if the device not match the drawable DPI. Otherwise he has to buy multiple Images.

So my problem is that I don't know how to find out the highest resolution for the question Image.

How should I proceed?

Comment: 1px = 1dp @ 160dpi (mdpi), all others are just scales of that, hdpi = 1.5, xhdpi= 2, xxhdpi = 3 & xxxhdpi = 4 times. Screen sizes vary from manufacturer - you should really deal in "bucket sizes" - always think in terms of dp (mdpi being the base), not dpi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step #1: Determine how big your image will be, in density-independent pixels (`dp`), based on the screen sizes you want to support (`small`, `normal`, `large`, `xlarge`) and your GUI design. That will be based in part on [the sizes in `dp` associated with those screen size categories](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range):

- `xlarge` screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
- `large` screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
- `normal` screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
- `small` screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

Step #2: Decide what is the maximum density for which you want to have dedicated artwork (versus having Android upsample from a lower density).

Step #3: Given your image size in `dp` and your desired maximum density, determine the maximum resolution in pixels.

For example:

- in Step #1, you decide that you will only work with `small` and `normal` screens, and given your GUI design, your image will be 120dp x 90dp
- in Step #2, you decide that your maximum density that you are going to worry about is `xhdpi` (320dpi = twice the `dp` basis of 160dpi)
- the result for Step #3 is 240px x 180px

Comment: Thank you. So I decided to support small, normal and large screen sizes and the maximum density will be xxxhdpi. But how do you get 120dp x 90dp in step 1? In your example you choose xhdpi with 320dpi. Why is the result of step 3 twice as much of step 1.

Comment: @DenoAgüero: "But how do you get 120dp x 90dp in step 1?" -- you know what your UI is. I do not, nor does anyone else. Presumably, you have an `ImageView`, and presumably, you have rules to size it. "Why is the result of step 3 twice as much of step 1" -- because 320 is twice as much as 160. `dp`, like CSS pixels, operate on a 160dpi basis.

Comment: My ImageView has a width of 150 dp and for the height I'm using wrap_content. Must I determine the height in dp? If I say the height is 90 dp and my maximum density is 640 (xxxhdpi) so the maximum resolution would be 360x600. Is that correct?

Comment: @DenoAgüero: "Must I determine the height in dp?" -- if you want to estimate a resolution, yes. Typically, you would do that by estimating the aspect ratio of the images (which might well be a fixed value) and determining the length of the non-fixed side that way. "Is that correct?" -- yes.